# Meteor router and url paramaters

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm having some trouble trying to use the URL parameters in meteor with iron:router.

On the home page if my app, I display a thread of posts. But I want to allow people to select a single thread by specifying its ID in the url. Like that, when someone click on a link to a specific thread like myapp/the_asked_id, he only see the data related to the thread. Otherwise, he see all threads.

I think it would be something where I get the data from the url like in PHP, and then check for the value / existence of this parameter : if it exists / has a correct value, I display the thread, otherwise I display all of them.

Here is what I've tried so far :

HTML link :

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle green-link" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Notifications" data-target="{{link}}">the link</a>
```

with {{link}} to be the _id from my collection to identify the required thread / doc to display.

Js link event :

```
'click .talkLink' : function(event, template){
      if($(event.target).hasClass('talkLink'))
      {
        console.log(event.target.dataset.target);
        console.log(event.currentTarget);
      }
      else {
        console.log(event.currentTarget);
      }
      Router.go('/', {_id: event.target.dataset.target});
    },
```

Router :

```
this.route('home', {
      path: '/:_id?',
      data: {
        threadId: (this.params._id || "")
      }
    });
```

But I can't get it working, as it currently always display me the not found template...

Could someone explain me what is going wrong and how I should proceed ?

Thank you,

David

Comment: At first glance, I don't see that you have a template called `home`. Where are the `<template name="home"></template>` tags?

Comment: Also, `data` points to a function that returns something, not an object. https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#rendering-templates-with-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few suggestions:

```
this.route('home', {
    path: '/:_id',
    data: function() {
        // assuming you have a collection called "Threads"
        return Threads.findOne(this.params._id);
    }
});
```

1. You need a template called 'home'.  It's data context will be the return of the `data` callback
2. You do not need to place a `?` in the path
3. `data` is a callback, in which you can access `this.params` within to find the correct document.

Comment: I have a template Home, i just didn't copied it here :P

Doesn't the ? means that this parameters is optionnal ?

Comment: Honestly I didn't know about the `?`.  Either way, you could rethink the route name, instead of placing the _id on the home route, instead place it on a `/threads/:_id` path